# change image in report builder using iif function

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0, iif-function

I'm working with sql server report builder and I'm trying to change the value of an image according to a chosen date from a parameter. 
I've selected external as source and in the expression window I have something like this:

```
=iif(Parameters!Date.Value <> 11.04.2013, "http://rack.0.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDEyLzEyLzA0L2I1L3doZXJlZG9nb29nLmJoTi5qcGcKcAl0aHVtYgk5NTB4NTM0IwplCWpwZw/4931e287/304/where-do-google-doodles-come-from--ff2932470c.jpg", " ")
```

but I receive the following message:

`Argument not specified for parameter 'TruePart' of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'.`

I'm pretty new to work with the report builder, so please someone help me find out the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pasted your expression into a sample report set up with a parameter **Date**, data type *Date/Time*, and got the same error when using the expression.

I resolved this by changing the data being compared to the parameter in the expression into a string that can readily be converted to a date, so from `11.04.2013` to `"11-Apr-2013"`:

```
=iif(Parameters!Date.Value <> "11-Apr-2013", "http://rack.0.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDEyLzEyLzA0L2I1L3doZXJlZG9nb29nLmJoTi5qcGcKcAl0aHVtYgk5NTB4NTM0IwplCWpwZw/4931e287/304/where-do-google-doodles-come-from--ff2932470c.jpg", " ")
```

This stopped the error occurring for me and worked as expected when I selected different dates; i.e. the URL on all dates except 11-Apr-2013.